# Checking asset versions with PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, assets

I'm coding a website using several JS/CSS Libs :
- for JS : Jquery, Bootstrap, Handlebars, etc.
- for CSS : Bootstrap, Font Awesome, etc.

I would like to compare the versions of all these assets with the ones available from the various repositories. For example, I'm using the 3.3.4 of Bootstrap and I would like to know if it is the latest or not (checking there is a 3.3.5 existing and comparing it to my 3.3.4).

How can do that with PHP? Can composer help (how to use it with php?)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Composer is used for php ,you have [bower](http://bower.io/) for js. about css theres no such a thing actually but you can use tools like grunt to check for differences between versions